# Different questions regarding Arduino C++ library coding style

Tags: c++, wire-library

I'm reading the two wire library in Arduino libraries and in the C++ source  code I found different methods which I don't know what they mean, in the following:

```
// Initialize Class Variables //////////////////////////////////////////////////

uint8_t TwoWire::rxBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
uint8_t TwoWire::rxBufferIndex = 0;
uint8_t TwoWire::rxBufferLength = 0;

uint8_t TwoWire::txAddress = 0;
uint8_t TwoWire::txBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
uint8_t TwoWire::txBufferIndex = 0;
uint8_t TwoWire::txBufferLength = 0;

uint8_t TwoWire::transmitting = 0;
void (*TwoWire::user_onRequest)(void);
void (*TwoWire::user_onReceive)(int);


// Public Methods //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void TwoWire::begin(void)
{
  rxBufferIndex = 0;
  rxBufferLength = 0;

  txBufferIndex = 0;
  txBufferLength = 0;

  twi_init();
}

void TwoWire::begin(uint8_t address)
{
  twi_setAddress(address);
  twi_attachSlaveTxEvent(onRequestService);
  twi_attachSlaveRxEvent(onReceiveService);
  begin();
}

void TwoWire::begin(int address)
{
  begin((uint8_t)address);
}
```

My first question, regarding to class variables:

1. Why has the author connected the variables to the class with scope-resolution operator "::"?
2. I want to understand the last two lines of class variables, I know they are function pointers, but I want to know more details and benefits of function pointers?

---

My second question, regarding to public methods:

1. There are three versions of the "begin" function, can someone explain why?
2. Why is begin(); called inside the second function declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why they connect the variables to the class with scope-resolution operator "::"?

Those are *static* variables. They don't exist within an instantiated class instance since they are common to *all* class instances - so they have to be defined elsewhere, and for that you need the full "class path" for them to associate them with the class itself.

> I want to understand the last two lines of class variables, I know they are function pointers, but I want to know more details and benefits of function pointers?

Yes, they are function pointers. They are used to store the address of functions the user supplies at runtime. Without them it is very hard for the user to tell the class which of his own functions should be called for various events.

> There are three versions of the "begin" function, can someone explain why?

This is called *function overloading*. It allows you to have the same function but provide different combinations of parameters. In this case one with no functions (in master mode) and two with different numeric parameters (for slave mode) with those numeric parameters in different storage formats.

> Why begin(); is called inside the second function declaration?

It saves having to duplicate all the code from the other begin() function within that function. You call the function with a numeric parameter, it does a little bit of "extra" work, then it calls the "common" begin code from the other `begin()` function. Code duplication is generally a bad thing since any changes you make have to be made in multiple places. This keeps the common code in one location, and the most convenient place for that is the `begin()` function that takes no parameters.

Comment: Guys, first of all thank you very much for Mr Code Gorilla for correcting my English it's really a honor for me that a friend in the technical field is interested to help me with my English skills :), and secondly, thanks to Mr Majenko for answering my questions. I'm really thrilled that one help me with my English and the other one helped me with my technical topic. I understood some answers and others not so quite, so I need more time to understand and comment again for the answers.

Comment: There are some complex things there you are looking at. May help: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/ - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Comment: 1. For the fisrt answer, I understood half of your answer as static variables are shared and that's it but I didn't understand the second half, "so they have to be defined elsewhere, and for that you need the full "class path" for them to associate them with the class itself." Do you mean by full path is to define their type and connect them with the class name? I think yes, and also I understood in the library that the author is defining them at the beginning and before class definition with the class name. OK this point is now obvious to me :)

Comment: @PerchEagle With a static variable the type is defined in the class, but the storage space for that variable has to be manually defined, and that is what those entries are. A normal variable has the storage space allocated in a class instance when it is created (e.g., `Servo myServo;` allocates the space for the variables within the Servo class). Static variables can't do that since the storage space isn't specific to any one object, but to all objects - so you have to manually create that storage space. And you do that by defining the variables in a source file. The variable's name is ...

Comment: ... `<ClassName>::<VariableName>`. You need the `<ClassName>::` bit so that the compiler knows you mean the variable in that class, not some other unrelated variable.

Comment: 2. The second answer is not obvious because I didn't implement it practically in my AVR C coding yet so I don't know the benefits of function pointers. 3. The third answer is obvious which is function overloading and now I see an example for function overloading but I don't know why the author implemented this function overloading. 4. The fourth answer is not clear.

Comment: Re 2: It is not a question of "benefit" - it's a question of how do you implement storing a function passed to you as a parameter, and function pointers are the answer. Re 3: Because he wanted to. It's a clean way of doing it, and you only have to remember "begin", not "beginMaster" and "beginSlaveInt" and "beginSlaveUint8" functions. Re 4: Which would you prefer: to write the same code 3 times or write it once and just call the function with it in?

Comment: OK, I understood your reply and the Servo example, but why would I need static variables anyway if its storage is shared with all instances?

Comment: Because static storage happens to be the correct solution to a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me Re 2, 3, 4 are OK to me because I have to implement these techniques to see the results for C++ applications.

Comment: Absolutely thank you for your answers I'm really thankful for your cooperation I've been away of coding because I was busy with my marriage and honeymoon it's been 1 month for my marriage :) I just started off reviewing coding these days :)

Comment: I got another question today :) Why the author put two functions to se the frequency or the clock? Regards, void TwoWire::setClock(uint32_t clock)
{
  twi_setFrequency(clock);
}

Comment: @PerchEagle The bulk of the Wire library code is actually a third party (probably written by Atmel) C library of routines. The `TwoWire` class is merely a C++ wrapper to those C functions to give an easy user interface. `TwoWire::setClock` merely calls the relevant function in that library (which is all in the `utility` directory) to do the actual setting of the clock.

Comment: Oh yeah, so clear thank you very much, I'm really happy with your answers :) Please see my new post at avrfreaks, but didn't find a quite clear answer. http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/twen-twint, or I should post it in this website in a new topic? Regards,